# Ubuntu crashing

Tags: keyboard

I have a REALLY annoying Dell XPS M1330 that keeps crashing.  I am using Ubuntu 13.10, and i think that I have 4 GB of ram, maybe less. (I got this about 2 years ago), and the thing worked just fine on opensuse, 12.10, and for a while, it worked on 13.10.  After a while, it kept on rebooting itself, when I was playing minecraft, or other things, such as pressing the [Super] key.  Are there any ways to solve this? (or am I just being stupid and needing to go back to 12.10?) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 12.10, Unity 2D has been discontinued. This is what probably been used on lower-spec computers - the Unity 3D desktop that has to be used (by default) instead, it can use up to  around 1/2GB of RAM, and even the overview uses hardware acceleration.

Before you go back to 12.10, you could try other desktop environments which should still work OK, like [XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/a/65222/1785960);

[image: xfce]

[GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/a/65223/178596);
[image: gnome]

or [LXDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/65131/178596):

[image: lxde]

and if you don't like how they look, they are nearly fully customisable ;-)

Comment: Okay. thanks for the help.  I didn't have much on here anyway, so i'm just going to go hop back onto 12.10, unless I try to dual-boot debian 7 with it, or something.